# last entered value row in group by Mysql

Tags: mysql

My Query-

```
SELECT id, MAX(sl),  details_sp FROM shareholderreceive GROUP BY id
```

and result

```
 id     MAX(sl)     details_sp  
1       76  
2       74  
3       64  
4       67  
5       69  
6       70  
10      72
```

But i need Those MAX(sl) Where details_sp column has last entered value.

My expected table is -

```
 id     MAX(sl)     details_sp  
1       72              Jul'16
2       74  
3       64  
4       62              Aug'16  
5       69  
6       70  
10      71              Aug'16
```

here, data type details_sp is Varchar.
What query do I need to get this in MySQL?

Answer (score -1):

What I think you mean is that when there is a details_sp filled in you need the sl value of that row and when there is no details_sp you need the max sl value?

If so, don't use MAX() but use the ORDER BY with the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT id, sl, details_sp 
FROM shareholderreceive 
ORDER BY details_sp DESC, sl DESC 
GROUP BY id
```

The only problem with this is that you can never order by a date when it is a varchar value. This means you can never get the latest entry with just a varchar as a date.

So if there is a way, make the details_sp a date value (when you don't have a day just use the first day of the month, so 2017-06-01 for juli 2017) and use DATE_FORMAT() in MySQL or date_format in PHP (or JAVA or etc).

Comment: Order by should after the group by clause and The other group by field are select by aggregate function.